# Cannot cancel runnable Java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I want to cancel my two tasks after 5 seconds but the code below doesn't work. For some reason if I don't submit the two tasks and comment out the cancel commands I get the "Program has finished..." line printed after 5secs. If I submit the two above tasks, the line never ever gets printed and tasks just go on forever.

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = (ScheduledExecutorService) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);


    Future<?> res1 = exec.submit(p);
    Future<?> res2 = exec.submit(c);

    exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            res1.cancel(true);
            res2.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Program has finished execution after 5s.");
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//task code
public void run() {
while(true){
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
        try{
            //do stuff
            ...
            System.out.println("Doing stuff");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried exec.awaitTermination as well but it didn't work.

Comment: You have two threads, and two tasks that do not end. When do you expect the 3rd task to start working?

Comment: emm... ok, thanks man that was really stupid from me.